# Shutter Stock API PHP Post Object formatting

Tags: php, json, object, curl

I am talking to the Shutter Stock API. I am certain the problem is not SS but more the formatting of my PHP Curl post as if I send this request via terminal I get a proper response.

The Terminal curl comand is as follows:

```
curl "https://api.shutterstock.com/v2/images/licenses?subscription_id=$SUBSCRIPTION_ID" \
         --header "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
         --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
         -X POST \
         --data '{
           "images": [
             { "image_id": "137111171" }
           ]
        }
```

so I am playing with sending this as a PHP curl instead and here is what I have:

```
$url = 'https://api.shutterstock.com/v2/images/licenses?subscription_id='.$SUBSCRIPTION_ID;
        $params = new Object();
        $params = {
            'images' : {'image_id' : '137111171'}
        };

        $headers = [
          'Content-Type: application/json',
          'Authorization: Bearer '.$ACCESS_TOKEN
        ];

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_decode($params));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Butterfly');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        /*$json = json_decode($response, true);
        if (json_last_error()) {
          echo '<span style="font-weight:bold;color:red;">Error: ' . $response . '</span>';
        } else {*/
        return $response;
```

The response form Shutter Stock is "Decode body failure" which is a custom error response. I think the problem is in the $params variable and how it is formatted. Problem is that this is a post, I suspect that on the other side SS is decoding this in a specific way. The proper curl parameter is in the bash curl above as:

```
--data '{
               "images": [
                 { "image_id": "137111171" }
               ]
```

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to properly format this particular --data value so that I can send it as a POST?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your PHP code contains invalid syntax, also PHP has no class named `Object`, but you're probably looking for `StdObject`, but even that doesn't make much sense here.. also you're not urlencoding $SUBSCRIPTION_ID . remove the invalid syntax parts, and use json_encode, not json_decode..

```
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode ( array (
        'images' => array (
                array (
                        'image_id' => '137111171' 
                ) 
        ) 
), JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY ) );
```

(edit, going by the comments, the api requires applicable data to be an array instead of an object, thus i added the JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY flag.)

Comment: Yes thank you. I know the php is invalid. I simply quit trying to goof with it.  I had also tried your approach and here is the response:`   URL = {"message":"Validation failed","errors":[{"code":"VALIDATION_INVALID_TYPE","message":"Invalid type: object should be array","data":{"image_id":"137111171"},"path":"$.body.images"}]} `

Comment: @Cybergei fkin nitpickers, use the `JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY` flag with json_encode 's second input parameter then. i updated the example code above.

Comment: @Cybergei oh, edit 2, i failed to see that images was actually an array of objects, fixed.

Comment: Excellent Job buddy. I have never seen that flag before but it appears to have worked. Send me a Ripple Address and I will gift tip you some XRP :)

Comment: Is flag `JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY` need for creating JSON?

Comment: @Cybergei haven't used XRP before, but here goes, rastUCMpqon29kVNsh2DLBtAsDPmMeZnVr

Comment: @TaronSaribekyan no, it just changes minor details about how the json is created. in json, `[]` is an array, and `{}` is an object , and on some data, both works, and when both works, php's json_encode function defaults to making it an object, but with this flag, php defaults to making it an array instead. check the documentations at http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php / http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php for more info.

Comment: @hanshenrik `json_encode` always will convert object and array to string independent of flag (both associative array and object will be converted absolutely same way). That flag can be used on json parsing: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php / http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php#constant.json-object-as-array.

Comment: `json_encode` ing the POSTFIELDS works for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you pass wrong `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` data. Try:

```
    $url = 'https://api.shutterstock.com/v2/images/licenses?subscription_id='.$SUBSCRIPTION_ID;

    $params = [
        'images' => ['image_id' => '137111171']
    ];

    $headers = [
      'Content-Type: application/json',
      'Authorization: Bearer '.$ACCESS_TOKEN
    ];

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Butterfly');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
```

Comment: No I had already tried that one first thing. Here is the return:  Notice: Array to string conversion in bla on line 212
URL = {"message":"Decode body failed"}  I also tried json_encode to convert to a string but no luck.

Comment: this is less wrong than OP's post which is outright invalid PHP syntax, but this will send the data in `multipart/form-data`-format, but according to the example, it wants the data in json format.

Comment: True is less wrong, and I have been trying appraoches for hours now. I simply quit trying to mess with it and decided was time to ask for help :)